# Why are my DLLs loading from SysWOW64 when they exist in the application directory?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, dll

I'm writing a 32-bit C++ application on Windows 8.1 x64 using Visual Studio 2013 that depends on Python 3.3 and libVLC. I have python33.dll, libvlc.dll, and libvlccore.dll in the same directory as my executable, which I also have set as the working directory under Project > Properties > Debugging. [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#search_order_for_desktop_applications), unless you're using the altered search path (which should only apply if you're using LoadLibraryEx to load the DLLs at run-time; in my case these DLLs are loaded at load-time), the application directory should always be searched before the system directory. However, according to Visual Studio, all three of these DLLs are being loaded from C:\Windows\SysWOW64. This is causing me problems as the version of libVLC I have there is much older than the one I'm trying to use.

That MSDN article only lists 3 exceptions to the normal search process. These DLLs are loaded as soon as the process starts, so obviously it couldn't be the system versions were already loaded (but just to be sure, I created a .local file since it mentioned redirection would override that, and it had no effect). I've checked the registry to see that they didn't somehow get registered as "Known DLLs", so that doesn't appear to be the problem. It's possible that python33 is being loaded as a dependency of Boost.Python, but even if it's loaded only by name the app directory should still be searched first, and in any case none of my other dependencies reference VLC. As a guess I tried marking the VLC libs as delay-load (I couldn't with Python due to data imports), and I got the following warnings, which I found interesting:

```
1>LINK : warning LNK4199: /DELAYLOAD:libvlc.dll ignored; no imports found from libvlc.dll
1>LINK : warning LNK4199: /DELAYLOAD:libvlccore.dll ignored; no imports found from libvlccore.dll
```

However, dumpbin shows that my compiled exe imports several functions from libvlc.dll.

I could of course replace or delete the system versions, but that's not really a solution if I ever attempt to distribute this application. I'm not really sure what else would be causing this. Can anyone suggest anywhere else for me to look?

Comment: It would be helpful to include the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: I don't have a problem with that, but I'm not really sure what that would be. The DLLs aren't loaded in code; it's all VS project settings.

Comment: The search for a DLL always starts in the directory in which the EXE is stored.  You left no breadcrumbs to guess what that EXE looks like or where it is stored, other than the very unwise  practice of storing executables in the operating system directory.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor to see the order in which your program searches directories for the DLL.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Hans. I'm not at my development computer now, but when I get back I'll try that and see if I can include some additional information. To clarify, I didn't place these DLLs in the system directory, they were already there. I have the standalone versions of Python and VLC on this computer as well and I can only assume they were placed there by their installers.

Comment: Process Monitor pointed me to the issue. I have this project set to copy the executable to my desired directory at the end of the build, but I never changed it to actually run from there, so it's been running out of the project directory. @Hans, if you want to post your suggestion as an answer, I'll accept it. As you said, I left no clue that this was the case; I set it up so long ago it didn't seem unusual to me.